# Frobenius element of unramified extension

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $L/F$ be an unramified extension of $p$-adic fields. Then it is Galois and $Gal(L/F)$ is cyclic, generated by an element $\sigma$ called the Frobenius element. Now, in the book I'm reading, the author states "The latter is characterized by the congruence $\sigma(x)\equiv x^q\mod\mathfrak{P}$ for all $x\in\mathcal{O}_L$, where $\mathfrak{P}$ is the maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_L$ and $q$ is the size of the residue field $\mathbb{L}=\mathcal{O}_L/\mathfrak{P}$."

I know that since the extension is unramified that $Gal(L/F)\cong Gal(\mathbb{L}/\mathbb{F})$ where $\mathbb{F}$ is the residue field for $F$. My question is shouldn't we have $p$ instead of $q$ in the above paragraph defining the Frobenius element? Don't we have $x^q=x$ in general?

Comment: You are right in that when $q=|\Bbb{L}|$ we have $x^q=x$ for all $x\in\Bbb{L}$. To fix the problem the exponent $q$ should be the size of the smaller residue field $\Bbb{F}=\mathcal{O}_F/\mathfrak{p}$ where $\mathfrak{p}$ is the maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_F$. Observe that $F$ can be any finite extension of $\Bbb{Q}_p$, so we don't know that $|\Bbb{F}|=p$.

Comment: I see. Looks like there was a typo in the book.

Comment: And how would you show $\sigma(x)\equiv x^q\mod(\pi_L)$ with $q$ the size of $O_F$'s residue field defines an element of $Aut(O_L/O_F)$ and that it generates the Galois group ?